# Way in Emacs to do a tags like search over all open buffers

Tags: search, emacs, tags, buffer

In Emacs, the tags-search command allows a search across files in your tags table.

It would be handy to have a similar search functionality but over the open buffers in your Emacs session.

Does such functionality exist today?  Or if not, can anyone offer simple code to extend Emacs to do this?

Comment: A related functionality is `dabbrev`, which completes the current word using words from all buffers. Unfortunately the code doesn't look like it could be easily adapted to tell you where it found a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question of [interactively search open buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641211/emacs-interactively-search-open-buffers) over at SO.  Check out the answers.  I'm partial to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641211/emacs-interactively-search-open-buffers/2641715#2641715).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that ibuffer allows you to do incremental search or regexp search in marked buffers.

Alternatively, there's some sort of "project" functionality from the CEDET guys that collects buffers into a group. I think they had some sort of search all files in project functionality, but I'm not positive about that.

I vaguely recall that you can also search all files from dired, but that would limit you to a single directory, so is probably not what you want.